# java hadoop job strange behavior in operation 1/double (ONE DIVISION a Double ) in reducer outputcollector

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, division

In a Hadoop MapReduce job write in Java
I have found, in the phase of REDUCE, an instability of the division. In the specific 1 / X with X double:

```
double sum = 0;
 while (values.hasNext())
 {
    sum += values.next().get();
 }
 if (sum != 0) {
    output.collect(key, new DoubleWritable(1/sum));
 } else {
   output.collect(key, new DoubleWritable(1));
 }
```

values is a Iterator.

When sum is different from ZERO sometimes write 1/sum and SOMETIMES WRITE sum.
It drive me crazy.
Thanks a lot

[Solved]
I had another problem, MAPPER and REDUCER interface (key-value) different. (Text, InteWritable) the first (Text, DoubleWritable) the second. 
I configured this stuff in the "main". The error continued, because I was wrong in putting this line:

```
conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
```

which requires the same interface (k, v) in mapper and reducer, which is not my case;
removed everything works.
Thanks to Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz, i have no reputation to endorse him

Comment: So you have never worked with floating points before?

Comment: And whats the question, anyway?

Comment: no, in hadoop mapredeuce job and java.

Comment: my question is "Why?" where is the mistake.

Comment: Hint: floating point addition is not commutative when adding more than two elements.

Comment: so I might add with the integers and assign the mutual in a double

Comment: Show some example output.  I have a hard time believing it's writing sum and not 1/sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that addition of floating point values is not commutative when calculating the sum (its cause is the limited precision of double). In simpler words: the sum is influenced by the order in which the elements are added.

This is demonstrated very nicely by this code:

```
public class DoubleSumDemo {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        final ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        // fill list with random values
        for (int i=0; i<1000000; ++i)
            list.add(Math.random());
        // sum the list, print the sum and then reorder the list elements
        while (true) {
            double sum = 0D;
            for (double element : list) 
                sum += element;
            System.out.println("sum is: " + sum);
            Collections.shuffle(list);
        }
    }

}
```

While the list is only filled once, it will print a different sum on each loop.